# Invalid Login for SugarCRM over REST

Tags: java, json, rest, sugarcrm

My java application generates:

```
{"application":"lukasync","user_auth":{"user_name":"admin","password":"03535a5ae1b5bff4401a7283c4570d8c"}}
```

Sends it with:

```
http://<My_Site>/service/v4_1/rest.php?method=login&input_type=json&response_type=json&rest_data={"application":"lukasync","user_auth":{"user_name":"admin","password":"03535a5ae1b5bff4401a7283c4570d8c"}}
```

But the answer it gets is:

```
{"name":"Invalid Login","number":10,"description":"Login attempt failed please check the username and password"}
```

The expected answer is a JSON string containing the session id.

I've checked that the username and the hash matches the ones in the database.
I also tried to URL Encode the JSON, but it ended up with the same result.

It's SugarCRM Version 6.5.15 (Build 1083)

Have I made some basic implementation error?

**Update:**
Apparently SugarCRM needs JSON to be ordered and accordning to sugarcrm.com/support/bugs.html?caseID=34925#issue_34925 they seem to think that is the right way to do it too. So user_auth needs to be the first object in the JSON string.

I've been told that they have fixed it for SugarCRM 7, but that wont be released until around mid next year(2014).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this JSON structure. It should work.

```
{
    "user_auth": {
        "user_name": "admin",
        "password": "03535a5ae1b5bff4401a7283c4570d8c",
        "version": "1"
    },
    "application_name": "RestCall",
    "name_value_list": []
}
```

The new URL would then be:`http://crm-shiruslabs.dontesta.it:8888/sugarcrm_dev_WebServices/service/v4_1/rest.php?method=login&input_type=JSON&response_type=JSON&rest_data={"user_auth":{"user_name":"admin","password":"03535a5ae1b5bff4401a7283c4570d8c","version":"1"},"application_name":"RestCall","name_value_list":[]}`

[image]

Comment: Isn't JSON supposed to be unordered?
When I do:

http://.../service/v4_1/rest.php?method=login&input_type=JSON&response_type=JSON&rest_data={%22user_auth%22:{%22user_name%22:%22admin%22,%22password%22:%03535a5ae1b5bff4401a7283c4570d8c%22,%22version%22:%221%22},%22application%22:%22RestCall%22}

It works, but as above when I have the application name before the user auth it gives me an error.
Time to file a bug?

Comment: Seems to be this bug: http://www.sugarcrm.com/support/bugs.html?caseID=34925#issue_34925
But apparently the SugarCRM developers thinks that it works as designed i.e it is designed to break the JSON standard.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is a bug in SugarCRM which I believe will not solve.

Comment: Yeah, I talked to them and apparently it's solved for version 7, but it wont be released until mid next year. Really stupid that they didn't implement JSON following the standard from the beginning.